# How to check if non-unique key contains specific value pairs?

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
    ID,
    status,
    timestamp
)
```

I would like to check for ID's that have status A, but also for ID's that have status B AND status C. I would like them to be placed into a count somewhat as follows:

```
SELECT 
ID
,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'A' then 1 
WHEN 
-- something like the following:
status = 'B'  and (status = 'C' AND [timestamp of C] > [timestamp of B]) then 1
else 0 END) as SUCCESS
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY ID
```

Do I need a `self join` here? How do I get the IDs that have this status = B & C with a timestampB < timestampC conditional?

Example table:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(ID, status, timestamp)
VALUES(1, A, 5)
VALUES(2,B, 3)
VALUES(2, D, 5)
VALUES(3, A, 5)
VALUES(4, B, 9)
VALUES(4,C,10)
```

Results should be:

```
1, 1
2, 0
3, 1
4, 1
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ids that have A and whose timestamp for B is less than C, then use:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       min(case when status = 'B' then timestamp end) < max(case when status = 'C' then timestamp end)
```

EDIT:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  min(case when status = 'B' then timestamp end) < max(case when status = 'C' then timestamp end)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as success_flag
from t
group by id
```

Comment: edited. I need the count of those satisfying the requirements, not just their IDs

Comment: @Runeaway3 . . . Just move the conditions to the `SELECT`.